# Newfies-dialer Call Reports module

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have **newfies dialer project**, i would like to add a new field in **Call Reports** section.

[image: Call reports]

I have lot of field that are unused in contact model. One of them can be used for this special id for my purpose.

How can i do that? Please help me anyone who familiar with `newfies-dialer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newfies-Dialer is based on the Django framework, so it's good to know about Django to hack on the project.

You will notice in Newfies-Dialer that there is a template called: dialer_cdr/templates/dialer_cdr/voipcall_report.html
in which we display the data that is passed from the view.

So then in dialer_cdr/views.py, you have a view function which is in charge of rendering template and pass it some data. There, you can either modify voipcall_list object to add extra data to it, like info from the contact model, or pass an other object to data.

Here a link to the function handling this view: https://github.com/Star2Billing/newfies-dialer/blob/v2.12.2/newfies/dialer_cdr/views.py#L169